# Thread does nothing after successful pthread_create

Tags: c++, pthreads

In my project I want to create thread which do nothing but append some string to textfile to test if it works. I'm using IDE Eclipse Juno on Ubuntu 12.04. Part of my code is:

```
pthread_t processThread;
threadData * thData = new threadData;
int t = pthread_create(&processThread, NULL, 
                       BufferedData::processData, (void *)thData);
```

where threadData is struct with parameters for thread. Thread start member function of class BufferedData so processData method is static. Its declaration is:

```
static void * processData(void * arg);
```

After this part of code I check t value - the returning value of pthread_create. Everytime it is equals to 0 so I suppose that start of thread was succesful. But still it does nothing - it doesn't append string to file. It doesn't matter what function processData do: append string to file, throw exception, write to cout or something else. It does nothing everytime.

I'm not experienced C++ programmer so I don't know what to check, edit or do to solve the problem. IDE doesn't give me any response that something is wrong, it faces as everything is ok.

Thanks for your answers.

EDIT:
the code of processData function:

```
void * BufferedData::processData(void * arg) {
HelperFunctions h;
h.appendToFile("log", "test");
    return 0;
}
```

appendToFile method write string "test" to file "log". This is tested in other projects and it works.

Comment: How about showing us the code of `BufferedData::processData`? That could give a clue what's going on

Comment: do you wait for thread to complete? using `pthread_join`

Comment: Most likely, your program terminates (probably by returning from `main`) before the thread has had a chance to do anything.

Comment: with pthread_join it works! Thanks. But what if I want to continue in code and do not want to wait for thread to finish its code?

Comment: to David Schwartz: yes, this is my problem. Now I get it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Now your thread will be finished in a time (not infinite), so this can help you :

```
int pthread_join(pthread_t thread, void **status);
```

In bellow `code`, when your thread created then `pthread_join` function waiting for a return from your thread. in this state use of `pthread_exit()` instead of `return` keyword.

Try this `pthread_join()` :

```
void *ret;
pthread_t processThread;
threadData * thData = new threadData;
int t = pthread_create(&processThread, NULL, 
                       BufferedData::processData, (void *)thData);

if (pthread_join(processThread, &ret) != 0) {
    perror("pthread_create() error");
    exit(3);
  }

   delete ret;      // dont forget to delete ret (avoiding of memory leak)
```

And use of `pthread_exit()` :

```
void * BufferedData::processData(void * arg) {
int *r = new int(10);
HelperFunctions h;
h.appendToFile("log", "test");
    pthread_exit(static_cast<void*>(a));
}
```

### General description

Allows the calling `thread` to wait for the ending of the target `thread`.

`pthread_t` is the data type used to uniquely identify a thread. It is returned by `pthread_create()` and used by the application in function calls that require a thread identifier.

status contains a pointer to the status argument passed by the ending thread as part of `pthread_exit()`. If the ending thread terminated with a return, status contains a pointer to the `return` value. If the thread was canceled, status can be set to `-1`.

### Returned value

If successful, `pthread_join()` returns `0`.
If unsuccessful, `pthread_join()` returns `-1` and sets `errno` to one of the following values :

Error `Code` :

```
Description :

EDEADLK
    A deadlock has been detected. This can occur if the target is directly or indirectly joined to the current thread.
EINVAL
    The value specified by thread is not valid.
ESRCH
    The value specified by thread does not refer to an undetached thread.
```

Notes:

When `pthread_join()` returns successfully, the target thread has been detached.
Multiple threads cannot use `pthread_join()` to wait for the same target thread to end. If a thread issues `pthread_join()` for a target thread after another thread has successfully issued `pthread_join()` for the same target thread, the second `pthread_join()` will be unsuccessful.

If the thread calling `pthread_join()` is canceled, the target thread is not detached